# How do I bind a string array(list of files in my case) to a variable in the item template of a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I bind a string array(list of files in my case) to a variable in the item template?

Here is what I have so far but I am not sure what to do for the code behind itemdatabound.

I am trying to put each url in the <% Photo_URL %> variable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

Page Code

```
<asp:Repeater id="unorderedList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="unorderedList_ItemDataBound">
   <HeaderTemplate>
       <ul class="thumbs noscript">
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
          <li>
            <a class="thumb" href='<%# Photo_URL %>'>
                <img src='<%# Photo_URL %>'>
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="download">
                    <a href='<%# Photo_URL %>'>Download Original</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
       </ul>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind

```
private void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] photos = Directory.GetFiles(ImagesLocation);
    unorderedList.DataSource = photos;
    unorderedList.DataBind();
}
protected void unorderedList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    //what goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
            <div class="download">
                <a href='<%# Container.DataItem %>'>Download Original</a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for the `ItemDataBound` event, you just need to use the `<%# Container.DataItem %>` syntax, like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
      <li>
        <a class="thumb" href='<%# Photo_URL %>'>
            <img src='<%# Container.DataItem %>'>
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="download">
                <a href='<%# Container.DataItem %>'>Download Original</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Container.DataItem` syntax:

```
<asp:Repeater id="unorderedList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="unorderedList_ItemDataBound">
   <HeaderTemplate>
       <ul class="thumbs noscript">
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
          <li>
            <a class="thumb" href='<%#Container.DataItem%>'>
                <img src='<%#Container.DataItem%>'>
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="download">
                    <a href='<%#Container.DataItem%>'>Download Original</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
       </ul>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to add a GridView in the ItemTemplate.  Set it's `DataSource` to `<%# Eval("string_list_name") %>` where string_list_name is the variable name of your List of strings.