# Confused on how to put a split string into a repeater from a db

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm taking a string from my db, splitting it, then wanting to put the split up pieces into a table within a repeater.

I have other methods I use to pull the data, and display it, however it's mostly listbox's and such and I'm unhappy with that as a table would be better.

```
            var query = from q in Session.CurrentContext.MENU
                    where q.CycNum == 24 && q.PerID == 3 && q.CatID == 12
                    select new
       {
          Item = q.ButDesc
       };
        rpt_menu.DataSource = query;
        rpt_menu.DataBind();
```

My string that's in the db is stored as "text|text|text|text", | separates what should be items in different tables, but this case it's just a long string stored as explained. (Item) is the name of the eval label in the repeater.

Obviously doing

```
            char[] Sep = { '|' };
        string[] data = Convert.ToString(query).Split(Sep);
        foreach (string x in data)
        {
            Item = x;
        }
            rpt_menu.DataSource = query;
        rpt_menu.DataBind();
```

wouldn't work, but it's the general idea what I'm needing to do, any tips would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `GridView` control inside the `Repeater` when the GridView is rendered in the HTML it anyway gets converted to an HTML `<table>`:

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class RepeaterExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var c1 = new ContextMenu { Title = "Context Menu 1", Items = "Menu1|Menu1|Menu1" };
            var c2 = new ContextMenu { Title = "Context Menu 2", Items = "Menu2|Menu2|Menu2" };
            rptMenu.DataSource = new List<ContextMenu> { c1, c2 };
            rptMenu.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenu item = e.Item.DataItem as ContextMenu;
        Label lblTitle = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblTitle");
        lblTitle.Text = item.Title;

        GridView gvItems = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("gvItems");
        gvItems.DataSource = item.Items.Split('|');
        gvItems.DataBind();
    }
}

public class ContextMenu
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Items { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMenu" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Font-Size="Large" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvItems" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
        <hr />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Copy the example above into a new .aspx page > understand how it works > apply to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop, just give the array to your control as it's data source.  Then in your binding HTML use Container.DataItem.

```
    char[] Sep = { '|' };
    string[] data = Convert.ToString(query).Split(Sep);

    rpt_menu.DataSource = data ;
    rpt_menu.DataBind();
```

Example  [How do I bind a string array(list of files in my case) to a variable in the item template of a repeater?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978945/how-do-i-bind-a-string-arraylist-of-files-in-my-case-to-a-variable-in-the-item)